# How to discard previous versions in Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

I've decided I don't need version control in my iOS Swift project, but due to previous commits my project has grown from like 3 megabytes to around 50 megabytes.

How do I delete all the previous versions so that I only have the last committed version (in effect to stop using version control)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the .git folder in the root directory.

Comment: In the root directory of what? I can't find the .git directory in my project.

Comment: In the root directory of your project. It's a hidden file, so you'll have to show hidden files. Type `com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` into the command line and relaunch Finder. Then you'll be able to see and delete the .git folder in Finder.